# Join that will return the same amount of records found on the left table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to write a sql statement that will return the same amount of records found in the left table.

For instance we have two tables, Transactions and Partners.  Due to how the tables were originally designed there does not exist a way to retrieve an exact matching pair.  IE. A transaction could have many partners that it relates to.

What I am looking to do is display all the transactions with a Partner ID.  If a transaction has more than one matching Partner ID then I need to take the first occurrence of the match and throw away the rest.  If a transaction does not have a matching Partner ID, I still need to display it, but with an empty or null value for the Partner ID.

Transaction Table

```
Transaction ID | ID 1    | ID 2
-------------- +---------+----------
T1             | A       | 1
T2             | C       | 3
T3             | B       | 1
T4             | D       | 4
T5             | A       | 2
```

Partner Table

```
Transaction ID | ID 1    | ID 2
---------------+---------+----------
P1             | A       | 1
P2             | B       | 2
P3             | C       | 3
P4             | C       | 3
P5             | D       | 4
```

Desired Results

```
Transaction ID| ID 1    | ID 2     | Partner ID
--------------+---------+----------+-----------
T1            | A       | 1        | P1
T2            | C       | 3        | P3
T3            | B       | 1        | Null
T4            | D       | 4        | P5
T5            | A       | 2        | Null
```

I feel like I need some form of outer join to make sure no transactions are not queried, but I cant decipher how to make sure no duplicate transactions are displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables have no concept of "first" record, without some column to specify the ordering.  But, the basic idea of what you want uses `left join` and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, p.partnerid
from transaction t left join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id1, id2 order by partnerid) as seqnum
      from partner p
     ) p
     on t.id1 = p.id1 and t.id2 = p.id2 and p.seqnum = 1;
```

This version takes "first" to mean "lowest value of partner id".

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `outer join` with `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select t1.transactionid, t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.transactionid  as partnerid, 
           row_number() over (partition by t1.transactionid order by t2.transactionid) rn
    from Transaction t1 
       left join Partner t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2
) t 
where rn = 1
```

This selects all records from `transaction` table and then only 1 from the `partner` table if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you know you don't want `P4` partnered with `T2` as well as `P3`, but I found this worked for me, assuming it's the `lowest ID`:

```
select t1.transactionid, t1.id1, t1.id2, min(t2.transactionid) as partnerid
from Transaction t1, Partner t2 where t1.id1 = t2.id1(+) and t1.id2 = t2.id2(+)
group by t1.transactionid, t1.id1, t1.id2
order by t1.transactionid, t1.id1, t1.id2
```

Comment: I simplified the tables greatly for the question, but basically each Partner would have a partner name.  In the table there might be 3 partners setup with different transactions but they would each have the same name.  All I need to display is that partner name, so it doesnt matter that one transaction would match to multiple partners since the column I am going after is the same between those partners.